# How to change the text of a label with Stringproperty() in kivy

Tags: python, android, kivy

I’m just trying to change the text of a label by changing the variable to which the text is defined, but it doesn’t work. Yet I used the Stringproperty().I would like, if possible, that as soon as we press the button the text changes directly, passing through the variable theText

How to solve this problem plz?

Here is my code that serves as an example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen


class MenuScreen(Screen):
    pass


class SettingsScreen(Screen):

    def change_text(self):
        self.root.theText = '1'

class MyScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    # This is the text that both Labels may display
    theText = StringProperty('0')


kv = """
MyScreenManager:
    MenuScreen:
        name: 'menu'
    SettingsScreen:
        name: 'settings'

<MenuScreen>:
    label_wid : ratio
    FloatLayout:         
        Button:
            text: "options"
            pos: 270, 240
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: root.manager.current = 'settings'
        Label:
            id:ratio
            # Use theText Property from MyScreenManager
            text: root.manager.theText
            pos: 0,90
            font_size:30
            color:1,0,0,1

<SettingsScreen>:
    FloatLayout:
        Label:
            id:ratio
            # Use theText Property from MyScreenManager
            text: root.manager.theText
            pos: 0,90
            font_size:30
            color:1,0,0,1
        Button:
            text: "options"
            pos: 270, 240
            size_hint: .30, .10
            background_color: 0,1,0,0.75
            on_press: root.change_text

"""


class Quizz(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Quizz'
        Window.clearcolor = (0, 1, 1, 0.25)
        return Builder.load_string(kv)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    Quizz().run()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems. First, when you assign a method call to a `Button` in `kv`, you must include `()`. Yes, just the opposite of everywhere else in python. So the `on_press` should be:

```
on_press: root.change_text()
```

Second, the `change_text()` method needs to reference the `MyScreenManager` instance, which is simply `self.manager` in the `SettingsScreen`. So the `change_text()` should be:

```
def change_text(self):
    self.manager.theText = '1'
```